# How do I close the about window in Python?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a file, that is a `main.py` file that loads `basic.ui` (GUI in Pyqtt5) and `about.ui` (pyqt5 about window) that is created with a qt designer with one button that when pressed will close the window.

I want all the commands to be from the first main.py file. When pressing the about button from the `main.py` file the `about.ui window` is open with success but I cannot close it with the pushbutton.

How can I do this?

main.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('basic.ui', self)
        ...
        ...
 
        self.actionAbout.triggered.connect(lambda: self._aboutWindow())
        self.show()


    def _aboutWindow(self):
        self.aboutWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        uic.loadUi('about.ui', self.aboutWindow)
        self.aboutWindow.show()


        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(clicked=lambda: self.close_about_window())



    def close_about_window(self):
        print('Close About Window')
 


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

about.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>420</width>
    <height>220</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>About MAC address spoofing</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>330</x>
     <y>190</y>
     <width>80</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>OK</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>50</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>DejaVu Sans</family>
     <pointsize>11</pointsize>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>This program</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

convert about.ui in about.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mac_about.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(420, 220)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 190, 80, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 400, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("DejaVu Sans")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "About MAC address spoofing"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "OK"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "This program"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would like an example to solve my problem

Comment: `self.aboutWindow.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.aboutWindow.close)`.

Comment: In Qt Designer, simply connect the button's `clicked` signal to the dialog's `close` slot. See: [Signals and Slots Editing Mode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-connection-mode.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following snippet, which is cleaner (convert about.ui to about.py first).

With `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close_about_window())` you can run the `close_about_window` function when the the button is clicked.
As @ekhumoro said in the comment, you could also do it in Qt Designer.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from about import Ui_Dialog

class Ui(QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Main Ui_Dialog Window from your about.py

        self._aboutWindow()

        self.show()

    def _aboutWindow(self):
        self.aboutWindow = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.aboutWindow.show()

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close_about_window())

    def close_about_window(self):
        # not sure which one do you want
        # self.aboutWindow.close() #  with this, you close the window generated from "self.aboutWindow.show()"
        self.close() # with this you will close the current window which is the window from about.py -->"self.show()"
        print('Close About Window')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Ui()
    app.exec_()
```